# Need to release a CGImage contained in a CALayer's contents property

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, calayer, cgimage

I have a `CALayer` object called `sublayer`. I use it as `self.sublayer` throughout my view controller because I have made it a property in my view controller's header file.

I set the sublayer's contents property equal to a `UIImage` object that is created using a `CGImageRef` object called `imageRef`:

```
self.subLayer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef].CGImage;
```

I then release the `imageRef` object right away now that it has been used to create the sublayer contents and it is no longer needed:

```
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

However, here is what is bothering me. Later on in the code I will no longer need `self.sublayer.contents` and I want to make sure I release the `CGImage` it contains properly.

If I NSLog `self.sublayer.contents` it will print this to the console: `<CGImage 0x146537c0>`

So I need to be able to release this `CGImage` as well.

I tried using this to release the `CGImage`, but the NSLog still prints the same to the console:
`CGImageRelease((__bridge CGImageRef)(self.subLayer.contents));`

If I use this, the NSLog will print to the console as `(null)`, but I am worried that this is technically not releasing the `CGImage`:

```
self.subLayer.contents = nil;
```

Does setting the sublayer's contents property to `nil` properly release the `CGImage`, or am I correct in thinking that it is not technically releasing the `CGImage`?

I am experiencing memory problems right now in my app so I need to make sure that I am releasing this `CGImage` properly.

Comment: Is `sublayer` the view's layer?

Comment: This is how I set sublayer: self.subLayer = [CALayer layer];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `contents` property on `CALayer` is a retaining property, meaning that it's setter implementation *more or less* does this:

```
- (void)setContents:(id)contents
{
    if (contents == _contents) return; // Same as existing value
    [_contents release];
    _contents = [contents retain];
}
```

So, when you set `nil` as the new contents, the old contents *is* released.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have to say I'm a bit disappointed. I thought I had finally found what was causing memory issues. Oh well.